# Поиск выдает не соответствующий запросу ответ

Tags: c#, ado.net

Пытаюсь осуществить поиск в базе по разным колонкам.
При поиске по Id все работает нормально.
Если искать в столбце Sku, результат не соответствует запросу.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataTable product = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataView productView;
        product.TableName = "Product";
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = "*********";
        connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "*********";
        connectionStringBuilder.UserID = "*********";
        connectionStringBuilder.Password = "*********";

        string commandSrt = "SELECT * FROM Product";

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandSrt, connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
        adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
        adapter.Fill(product);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = product;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        productView = new DataView(product, "", "Sku", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);

        int name = productView.Find(textBox1.Text);

        if (name != -1)
        {
            DataRow row = product.Rows[name];

            textBox2.Text = row["Name"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = row["Price"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = row["Sku"].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = row["Id"].ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корректно стал работать поиск, если убрать строку

```
DataRow row = product.Rows[name];
```

И заполнять данные таким образом

```
int name = productView.Find(textBox1.Text);

            if (name != -1)
            {
                textBox2.Text = productView[name]["Name"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = productView[name]["Price"].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = productView[name]["Sku"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = productView[name]["Id"].ToString();
            }
```